# Import image in scilab

Tags: scilab

I'm a beginner in Scilab and I need to import a jpg image into the environment. But when I use `ReadImage`, Scilab tells me 'ReadImage' is undefined. Why's this? (Ubuntu+Scilab5.4.1+IPT)

Comment: For scilab 6.0 use: atomsInstall("IPCV") and imread("my.jpg")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### IPT

I took a look at the help browser and it seems it is indeed not defined in Image_Processing_Tool_2. The [Atoms package page](http://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/IPT2/2.0) also mentions that:

> This toolbox provides some supplementary functions for Image Processing Algorithms

You need another toolbox to read an image.

### Alternatives

I'm not sure if you are required to use that toolbox specifically. But you could also take a look at [other image_processing toolboxes](http://atoms.scilab.org/categories/image_processing) altogether.

### SIVP

For example [SIVP](http://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/SIVP), which is also the only partner module in the image processing category.[image: Scilab partner module]

Reading in an image is as simple as:

```
im = imread(SCI + '/contrib/sivp/images/lena.png');
imshow(im);
```

### Help browser

The help browser in Scilab is usually pretty good and also contains examples. The toolboxes you add through the ATOMS module manager also add a section to the help browser. If you want to know which functions are implemented in a toolbox and how to use them, this is a good place to start looking.

Comment: Thanks. But I encountered another problem when loading SIVP. It reads "link: The shared archive was not loaded: libtiff.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". How to handle this?

Comment: It is telling you, you are missing a dependency. You can install this with `sudo apt-get install libtiff4`.

Comment: For scilab 6.0 use: atomsInstall("IPCV")